# Getting the list of all the views in a model on Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am working on a Revit plugin to run on Forge (Design Automation app) that exports a 3D view through a custom exporter. As an input argument, it requires the name (or ElementID) of one of the 3D views from the Revit model. Is there a way to query the name of the views of a Revit model through other Forge solutions (like Data Management API)?

I couldn't find anything, if there is not an http api for that I assume I have to do it as part of my plugin run. What's the best to do that then?

Should I have a separate plugin that extracts the view names?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I am not sure if these are interchangeable but the forge api does expose the (3d) views in a model via [this endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/). However this does require an already translated model which i am not sure you're using (I am not that well versed in Revit). Anyways hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Hi Samuel, yes that's exactly what I need. So to get the views from a Revit document that's on BIM 360, I need to download it first, then upload it herehttps://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/ ?

Is there a way to just provide a signed URL instead of downloading and uploading?

Comment: Hi Ehsan, if the document is already living in the BIM360 docs of your project(s) then it should already be translated. This makes sense since it is also viewable in BIM360. If you know URN of the translated document you could use this id to reference the mentioned endpoint and get the different views. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it appears that you have very little experience with Revit API add-ins. Maybe you should take a look at the [getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) first and work through the video tutorial. It explains a lot of important fundamentals, including covering this current question of yours.

The (almost) one and only way to retrieve elements from the Revit database is to use a filtered element collector. That would be the method of choice to find the element id of the 3D view you are looking for.

You cannot have searched very exhaustively, because many discussions by The Building Coder on the [custom exporter](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.1) and other topics include a code snippet showing how to pick a 3D view suitable for exporting.

To ensure you really have a 3D view set up just as you need it, you might prefer [creating a new one from scratch](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.37).

Out of curiosity, is your task associated with the discussion thread on [Revit API vs. ReCap API for historic project](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/revit-api-vs-recap-api-for-historic-project/m-p/9465150)?

Comment: Hi Jeremy. The question is not about getting the list of views in a Revit plugin, it's about getting them using Forge HTTP APIs. Appologies for the confusion, changed the title to make it more clear.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the clarification. Does that return the same views as the ones you marked for translating to Forge in the Revit model?

Comment: The idea is to first get the full list of 3D views, then send one of them as an input argument to the plugin (which will be deployed on Forge) so we can export the view through a custom exporter.